# Why is my Yucca plant not growing?

Tags: houseplants, growth, yucca

I was given this plant and when it was given to me it already had the first leaves already grown.

I’ve had the plant for about a 2 months and nothing has changed. Currently using Miracle-Gro potting mix as the soil.

[image: Yucca plant]

Is this the only plant going to grow on it? I feel like the plant has done nothing in months.

Comment: We had a similar Yucca with one little branch. One day it put out roots at the base of the trunk. Then we separated it from the trunk and planted it. It is growing fine ever since. Mind that in our case some 1-3 cm roots were already growing we did not have to root it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

They usually don't grow super fast, so I would suggest being patient. Looks like it's in a well-lit place, keep in mind that they don't like too much direct sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to grow faster (and with more branches), you can keep it outdoors for the summer. I have noticed that when you put a yucca outdoors in summer, full sun and rain once in a while will stimulate branching. Of course you'll have to let the plant acclimate first, by putting it in the shade first and slowly increase the number of hours of full sunlight. Also be sure you have good drainage, so a container with holes. Furthermore, you can give it some fertilizer to stimulate more growth.